# Как сделать, что бы функция автоматически переходила на след. страницу и продолжала работать?

Tags: javascript

Есть код:

```
const rows = document.querySelector('div#mobile_table_pills table')
          .querySelectorAll('tbody tr');

for (const row of rows) {
  const lastCellText = row.querySelector('[data-th="ETFdb Pro"]').innerText;
  if ( lastCellText === 'A+' || lastCellText === 'B+') {
    console.log(row.querySelector('[data-th="Symbol"]').innerText);
  }
}
```

и нужно что бы этот код работал не только на той странице на которой я его запустил но и автоматически переходил на следующую и совершал там все действия повторно и так пока не дойдет до конца[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer и переместите этот код в node.js скрипт. Навигируйтесь по страницам из node.js скрипта.